# Trying to add input field when a click happens but gets missing argument list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-4

I am trying to add input field using laravel's Form helper when an element is clicked for that I am doing this

```
    $('#segment-create').click(function(e){
        $('#segments').append("<div class='clearfix'> <div class='selectbox boxed pull-left'> {{ Form::selectopt('contact_property[]', [ 'class' => 'form-control pull-left', 'rel' => 'noresize' ], [ 'User Activity' => [ 'Clicked in the last' => 'clicked_last', 'Opened in the last' => 'opened_last', 'Not clicked in the last' => 'not_clicked_last', 'Not opened in the last' => 'not_opened_last' ], 'User Property' => [ 'City' => 'city', 'Age' => 'opened_last', 'Name' => 'name' ] ] ) }} <span class='pull-left' style=' width:50px; text-align:center; line-height:34px;'>is</span> <div class='selectbox boxed pull-left'> {{ Form::select('operator[]', array('0' => '=', '1' => '>', '2' => '≥', '3' => '<', '4' => '≤', '5' => '<>' ), null, ['class' => 'operator form-control pull-left']); }} <span class='pull-left' style=' width:50px; text-align:center; line-height:35px;'>to</span> <div class='pull-left'> {{ Form::text('value[]', null, ['class' => 'filter-name form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Filter value']) }} </div> <div class='pull-left'><a href='#' class='right cbx-filter cbx cbx-checked filter-checkbox'>&nbsp;</a> </div> </div> </div> </div>");
        e.preventDefault();
        // to check as complete todo list
        shoot({segment_name:$('#new-segment-name').val()}, 'POST');

    });
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here but I get this error in firebug console

[image: Firebug console error]

Answer (score 0):

For me, it's a not good idea to append too much HTML code in javascript. 
As solution I propose to create a new blade file, which you will render if needed, and then append rendered file.

```
$('#segment-create').click(function(e){
    $.get('/url-to-remder-html', function(answ) {
        $('#segments').append(answ);
    });
    e.preventDefault();
    // to check as complete todo list
    shoot({segment_name:$('#new-segment-name').val()}, 'POST');
```

});

Or just try to use regular HTML on that part of code.

Comment: wouldn't it just increase the http requests?

Comment: In your case it's the best solution. Or you can store your html code hidden and then get it and append whenever toy need.